# In 2022, is it still not possible to upload files AND directories with the input file DOM field?

Tags: javascript, html

I've read a lot of articles by now that it's now possible to select `directories` as well as `files` from an `input file` field:

```
<input type="file" directory multiple>
```

Apparently you have to choose one or the other.

Has anyone found a way to make it possible to select both with just one `DOM element`?

Why is this feature not supported after a decade of requests?

Comment: Well, that features allow you to upload a single directory with any number of files or subdirectories. It doesn't allow you to upload multiple directories at once.

To achieve something like uploading multiple directories, you can use 3rd party plugins to achieve that using drag and drop for example.

And I don't think stackoverflow is the right platform to ask why a specific feature isn't implemented.

Comment: "Why is this feature not supported after a decade of requests?"  Because Billy Joe said so?  We totally know this and how all the browser companies make these choices.  Please build an open source browser with this feature and let us know how it went with yours!